# Ubuntu will not allow WiFi password more than 61 characters

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, password

My WiFi password is 64 characters and the connect button is only clickable until 61 characters. Any help would be appreciated. I am using wpa security.

Comment: sorry please read new edit.

Comment: No spaces at the beginning and weird how it only allows 61 before the connect button becomes grey.

Comment: fixed it just had to type it instead of copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Network manager will accept 63 ascii characters or 64 hex characters for WPA and WPA2 if you type it in; please do not use cut and paste if you are having problems.

The 63 ascii characters are taken as a passphrase and converted to a 256 bits hex key. The 64 hex characters are the key as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WPA_key - - so I suspect there may be leading spaces in the entry box before you start typing. Please try again after backspacing all the way left